# Выделенный текст в поле ввода при открытии всплывающего окна (bootstrap popover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть такая форма:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="image-copy-to-clipboard image-copy-to-clipboard-icon" role="button" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"
       title="Press Ctrl+C to copy page ID" data-html="true"
       data-content="<form><input type='text' placeholder='' value='#{{page.Id}} : {{page.Title}}' autofocus /></form>"></div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии всплывающего окна, с полем ввода, в котором есть текст, был выделен весь текст и фокус стоял на поле ввода, чтобы можно было нажать ctrl+c и сразу скопировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть специальный объект в JavaScript: [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). Почитайте про него, должно помочь. Или у `input` есть метод `select`